# How to capture on object with a broken image url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An API consumes data, which includes an attribute (image_url) used to store an image.
However, on occasion that file does not exist.

Is there a way in Ruby to validate an objects of a class - say Article - and NOT process the broken images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Net::HTTP.get_response` to check for response of the potentially broken image

```rb
image_url = Article.find(params[:id]).image_url # Potentially broken image url
result = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(image_url))
```

And then you can check `result.code`.

If image exists and available you will get

```rb
result.code # => "200"
```

Otherwise

```rb
result.code # => "404" | or any other non-success code
```

And then do what you want depending on `result.code` result